# Inserting input fields with value from another input JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert multiple hidden input fields with a value from another input field.

HTML

```
<div id="FormWrapper"></div>
```

FormWrapper is inside the form. I tried adding an input inside and the post value is working. The valueFromOtherInput also has value.

```
$('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'valueFromInputFields[]',
            value:$('#valueFromOtherInput').val()
            }).appendTo('#FormWrapper');
```

But the post value is not there when I submit the form.

Comment: You are aware that `#valueFromInput` is targeting an element with the **`ID`** attribute of `valueFromInput` and not the name. Also you have no quotes for your `value` attribute.

Comment: What you've written is a little ugly, but it works: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/51xb4611/), so what aren't you showing us? What errors do you have?

Comment: @DavidThomas without quotes could break when rendered depending on what the other value contains, for example spaces

Comment: When I submit the form, the post value form valueFromInput is not there, seems that the input field is not added.

Comment: @charlietfl: of course, but without knowing anything more of the OP's problem, attempts or results it's hard to offer anything other critique of the question in order to gain clarity. Incidentally that was the point made in [RomanPerekhrest's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41418083/82548) which may be correct, but remains a guess based on limited information.

Comment: @DavidThomas agreed...just suggesting that even the demo you said works can easily be broken by doing `value=" te  st"` on existing input

Comment: It worked when I changed the input type to text, but when I submit the post value still not there.

Comment: Btw I'm using php to process the post data.

Answer (score 1):

The inserted value should be enclosed by quotes:

`var hiddenInput = $("<input type='hidden' name='valueFromInput[]' value='" + $('#valueFromInput').val() + "'>");`

*But the post value is not there* - Also make sure that `$('#valueFromInput').val()` exists(not empty)

Comment: It only requires quotes if the value contains white-space (which isn't stated in the question), though you may well be correct about that being the problem.

Comment: When I submit the form, the post value form valueFromInput is not there, seems that the input field is not added.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than concatenate try creating as a jQuery object and use methods or options to set properties

```
var hiddenInput =$('<input>', {
         type:'hidden', 
         value:$('#valueFromInput').val(), 
         name:'valueFromInput[]'})
```

Or

```
var hiddenInput =$('<input>').attr({name:'valueFromInput[]',type:'hidden'})
                             .val($('#valueFromInput').val());
```

Is easier than checking for missing quotes and if you don't do it right will get syntax error thrown

Comment: I can now add the form element, but when I submit it, the post value is not there. I'm using php btw

Comment: Is `#FormWrapper` the form element or inside the form element? If neither and it wraps the form then the input needs to be inside the form

Comment: Yes #FormWrapper is inside a form element. See edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'valueFromInput[]',
    value:$('#valueFromInput').val()
}).appendTo('#FormWrapper');
```

Runtime adding try this

```
$("#FormWrapper").submit( function(eventObj) {

   $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'valueFromInput[]',
        value:$('#valueFromInput').val()
    }).appendTo(this);

    return true;
});
```

Comment: No good, when I submit the form, the name is not there, it seems that the input field is not added

Comment: I will add multiple input fields first before submitting. I tried the runtime adding but still not working. Post value still isnt there.